# IOS: Open UIView at Vertical coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone know of a way to load a view controller at a point other than the top.  This would be similar to opening a web page part way down ie `<a href="http://~mypage.html#target">Go to Target</a>`

This is not a tableview or webview so the point is not to go to a specific row of the table or place in the webview.  Rather it is a regular UIVIewController and the point is to go to a specific vertical point on the screen where there is some relevant content.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: I ended up using the following, not as elegant as I was hoping, but adequate:

```
-(void) raiseView:(float) float {
    CGRect contextRect = self.view.bounds;
    float boundsY = contextRect.origin.y;
    contextRect.origin.y=boundsY+float;
    self.view.bounds = contextRect; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I assume you're using a scroll view to contain your content?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up further on controller based interface and how to best use the common practices to your advantage.

My suggestion would be to rely on the presentation styles available to a`UIViewController`. Here would be an example of presenting a view controller over the current view:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;           
[currentViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
        // Do whatever you need to here
    }];
```

Then upon completion, you can do anything you need to for presenting your content. Here you can simply set the controllers view to be whatever frame you desire (with, in your terms, any top point you would like). This way you can present a VC to the user and display anything you need **on top** at the point relevant to the content on the previous view.

Happy coding!